# Looping through a list and applying the same manipulation to them

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe which is essentially daily imports for each country in a given area.
I need to make a new dataframe for each country.

Example;

```
Spain = df[['Date', 'Spain']]
Spain['Date']= pd.to_datetime(Spain['Date']) 
Spain = Spain.groupby([Spain.Date.dt.year,Spain.Date.dt.month]).mean()
Spain = Spain.unstack()
Spain = Spain/1745
Spain = Spain.round()
```

I am not very experienced with loops but is there any way I could create a list of all the countries and make a loop that would loop through that list to save me from writing the above code for each of the 100+ countries?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is possible add some data sample 3 rows, 3 columns ? finally need one big DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule in pandas is try [dont loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas).

I think you need [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot first:

```
df1 = df.melt('Date', var_name='country', value_name='val')
df1['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']) 
df2 = (df1.groupby(['country', df1.Date.dt.year,df1.Date.dt.month])['val']
           .mean()
           .unstack()
           .div(1745)
           .round())
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, is this using Python3?

I'm on Python2 and getting the following error;

"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'melt'"

Comment: @spcol Use `df1 = pd.melt(df, 'Date', var_name='country', value_name='val')`

Answer (score 1):

I have never used pandas so I will try an alternative answer:

You can make code that will write all of the code for you with the countries specified in a list. For example:

```
country = ['Spain', 'Italy']
code = ''

for item in country:
    code += f"{item} = df[['Date', '{item}']]" + '\n'
    code += f"{item}['Date'] = pd.to_datetime({item}['Date'])" + '\n'
    code += f"{item} = {item}.groupby([{item}.Date.dt.year, {item}.Date.dt.month]).mean()" + '\n'
    code += f"{item} = {item}.unstack()" + '\n'
    code += f"{item} = {item}/1745" + '\n'
    code += f"{item} = {item}.round()" + '\n\n'
```

When you go to `print(code)` you will get the following:

```
Spain = df[['Date', 'Spain']]
Spain['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Spain['Date'])
Spain = Spain.groupby([Spain.Date.dt.year, Spain.Date.dt.month]).mean()
Spain = Spain.unstack()
Spain = Spain/1745
Spain = Spain.round()

Italy = df[['Date', 'Italy']]
Italy['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Italy['Date'])
Italy = Italy.groupby([Italy.Date.dt.year, Italy.Date.dt.month]).mean()
Italy = Italy.unstack()
Italy = Italy/1745
Italy = Italy.round()
```

Which you can then copy/paste to your actual program.